# backing up a branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I am going to create a branch to work on my code, since the trunk is messed up in ways unimaginable (but that's not the issue). How can I periodically backup the branch I create. It would be located on my companies server, and I wasn't sure if periodically checking out the branch into a new folder is equivalent of "backing up my branch"?

Is that any different than just going to the Repo and copying the folder to my desktop? Do the .svn files contain everything I need to retain my branch history, and be able to revert to previous revisions?

Thanks!

Update **

The reason I ask is because I don't know if someone is going to come along one day and delete the branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thus Spaketh [Chobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173432/chobo):**

*Update* **

*The reason I ask is because I don't know if someone is going to come along one day and delete the branches.*

---

In Subversion, everything you do is reversible. Even if you delete a branch, you can get it back by simply copying it back from the revision before it was deleted.

For example, let's say your branch was deleted back in revision 100: We'll copy the branch back using the `@99`

```
$ svn cp -r99 svn://svn/branches/my_branch@99 svn://svn/my_branch
```

And, now it's back!

If you really want to protect your branches, you can use pre-commit hooks that prevent people from modifying folders and files. I have one I use [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/new_svn_hooks.zip).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to backup a branch, Subversion is a version control system.  When changes happen, you know who did it, when they did it, what they changed and you can even undo their changes.  This is what a version control system does.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your svn server like this:

Every time you make a change to the state of the server, it creates a snapshot of that state that is identified with the revision number.

Any time you want to reference that state, you check out that revision number.

now, that isn't exactly how it works - it would be incredibly inefficient space wise (and probably time wise too) if it created an entirely separate snapshot for every change. But, it is designed to allow you to operate as if it did that, and it does recreate it like that for you.

So your backup consists of doing this

Opening a document (let's call it backup.txt).

doing an SVN INFO on the repository to get the current revision number

Writing down "Backup  " and there's your log that says "I made a backup on this date. To get that backed up state, I just check out the revision in the log."

Basically, what you're asking for not only is built into subversion, but indeed is **the purpose of subversion**. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do the .svn files contain everything I
>   need to retain my branch history, and
>   be able to revert to previous
>   revisions?

No. The .SVN folders do not keep any history. All the history is in the repository on the server, and that is what you should backup.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to *back-up* your branch. A revision control keeps all the revisions with it. Anytime, you want to check out a version, you can run [checkout command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) with the version number

```
svn checkout -r 911 svn://url/to/file/or/dir/tobe.checked/out to/this/location/on/my/machine
```

refer: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html